# find the order of the element $ \ (1,3) \ $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ \ \phi: \mathbb{Z}_6 \to Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3) \ $ be defined by $ \ \phi_ 1=f \ , \ \phi_2=i $ , where $ \ f(n)=2n , \ $ $ \ i \ $ is the trivial automorphism. In  $ \ \mathbb{Z}_3 ⋊ \phi (\mathbb{Z}_6) \ $ **find the order of the  element** $ \ (1,3) \ $ ,

where $ \ ⋊ \ $ denote the semi direct-product.

**Answer:**

I got something as below:

The order of $ \ (g,h) \ $ is  a multiple $ \ k \times o(h) \ $ , where $ \ k \ $ divides the order of $ \ g \ $ (not necessarily order of $ \ g \ $).

Following the above rule,

we have to find the order of $ \ 3 \ $ in $ \ \phi(\mathbb{Z}_6) \ $ and order of $ \ 1 \ $ in $ \ \mathbb{Z}_3 \ $.

Order of $ \ 1 \ $= $3 \ \ $ in  $ \ \mathbb{Z}_3 \ $

**But I am unable to find the order of** $ \ 3 \ $ **in the group** $ \ \phi(\mathbb{Z}_6) \ $ .

I think we have to use the given information.

Help me doing thsi

Comment: Can you please clarify: is this a question about two different possibilities for $\phi$, namely $\phi=i:n\mapsto n$ and $\phi=f:n\mapsto 2n$?

Comment: Yes , you are correct

Comment: Well in that case you can do $\phi_2$ surely, as it's abelian and the order of $1$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is 3 and the order of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}^6$ is 2.

Comment: And in the other case $(0,3)$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by negating everything, so we'll get that $(1,3)$ is an involution just like the product of $(123)$ and $(12)$ in $S_3$.